# What does adding two registers in square brackets mean?

Tags: pointers, assembly, x86, cpu-registers, addressing-mode

What adding two registers together in square brackets mean?

I have a question about these lines of code:

```
"mov al, [ebx+edx];"
"mov [ecx+edx],al;"
```

I know that mov instruction should move values from source to destination. But I don't really know what `[ebx+edx]` and `[ecx+edx]` does.

Is it simply adding two registers and then saving values in the memory?

Comment: Yes, it is adding then saving to destination.

Comment: The square brackets indicate a memory reference in Intel assembly syntax.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly you're adding two adresses from square brackets and then saving value into the memory in this example: "mov al, [ebx+edx]"?

Comment: One of those registers within the brackets would be the _base_ address, and the other would be an _index_ which is scaled by some factor (in the case the implicit factor 1). So yeah, you're accessing memory at whatever address the values of those two registers add up to. See _3.7.5  Specifying an Offset_ in Intel's manual.

Comment: ecx and edx combine to make an address.  we know it is an address/memory reference because that is what the brackets mean.  so these are reading or writing a byte at the address ebx+edx.  if ebx is 0x1000 and edx is 0x20 then it is reading or writing from 0x1020 to/from the al register.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will add the values of the two registers and subsequently use them as a memory address reference to either retrieve the value at that register:

```
 MOV EDX, [EBX+EAX]
```

or store a value to that location:

```
 MOV [EBX+EDX], ECX
```